# Adjust legend text size in pie chart to fit segment size (CorePlot)

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

Is there any way to scale the segment's text label/legend according to their size. For example if they segment is really small, the label would decrease in size/scale to not get cut off by separators.

Example:

[image: Pie chart Example]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plot won't automatically adjust the labels, but you can use custom data labels to adjust the text style and/or offset for individual labels based on your data.

Comment: Can't you just use attributed labels with a specific font setting there?